# Prerequisites for "Lotte in Weimar"?

Tags: literature

I've started reading "Lotte in Weimar" (at least: I'm trying to), and I noticed many references to "Die Leiden des jungen Werthers" through the main character of Charlotte Buff. Should I read "Die Leiden" first, before reading "Lotte in Weimar"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the German language itself or its usage but rather about, well, a novel.

Comment: @Em1 - So Thomas Mann's or Goethe's writings have nothing to do with the German language? Strange. Also, what is the "literature" tag then for?

Comment: I did say: your question has nothing to do with the German language. - If, however, there's anything inside those books that you don't understand, you can ask that here. But the order in which books should be read is NOT about languages at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas Mann's 1939 novel 'Lotte in Weimar' recounts a fictional reunion between Goethe and the object of his youthful passion, Charlotte Buff.

One of the most famous - and infamous - works in the history of literature. Also known as one of the greatest love stories in world literature.

So yea, i think you should read 'The sorrow of young Werther' first.

I hope this helped you a little.